# Running ndk-build from sublime text 2

Tags: android-ndk, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I am trying to run ndk-build on an android NativeActivity project, from within Sublime text 2. I want to be able to parse compile errors within sublime text.

I have set the following sublime-build file

```
{
    "cmd": ["ndk-build", "-j"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "[path to my NativeActivity project]",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Clean",
            "cmd": ["ndk-build", "clean"]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I hit ctrl-b to build I get the following output....

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'ndk-build', u'-j']]
[dir:  [path to my NativeActivity project]]
[path: C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Tcl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;c:\Progra~2\CVSNT;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\android-ndk-r10e;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin]
[Finished]
```

Comment: Where is the `ndk-build.exe` file located? Is that location within the path displayed in the error message?

Comment: Yes that is the location of bdk-build in the path. It is C:\android-ndk-r10e